# extracting data from mysql db to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql databases with the same structure in each.

I want to take selected data from one db to the other.

One of the tables holds mutiple rows of data and I was looking at looping through the rows and doing inserts into the second db table but realised that as soon as I connect to the second db I will lose the connection to the first and the loop will fail.

Is the a robust and 'proper' way of doing theis rather than creating an array and then running an insert loop in the second db from the array?

currently I am using two different lots of credetials to access each db.

the API fuctons I am using are mysql_query and mysql_insert.

the reason i need to do this is I have a backend system that allows me to upload templates to the server, some are live and some are not.

the second db holds user details and details of any templates that they have selected.

btw I am working with php.

many thanks in advance and I hope I am not asking you to spoon feed me

cheers
Barry

Comment: 1. Do you use different credentials to access these databases? Which API (function names) you are using? 3. Why do you need such a transfer at all? Please answer not in comment but by editing your question

Comment: You'd probably be much better off just dumping the database from the source and restoring it to the destination.

Comment: GordonM, I need to do this on the fly. The user will select a template from db1 and the details of that template needs to be pushed in the db holding the user details, which is db2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to use 2 connections simultaneously by using $link_identifier parameter in mysql_* functions:

```
$connection1 = mysql_connect('host1', 'user1', 'password1');
$connection2 = mysql_connect('host2', 'user2', 'password2');

... 

$resource = mysql_query('SELECT .....', $connection1);

...

mysql_query('INSERT .....', $connection2);

...

mysql_close($connection1);
mysql_close($connection2);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. mysql_connect has an extra parameter `new_link`.
2. mysql_connect returns a connection resource.
3. mysql_* functions can use that resource variable to make their calls on the certain connection.

So, just create 2 connections returning their resources and then use these resource variables to tell mysql_query() which database to use